# How can I robustly infer the tail shape of a distribution from data?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, fitting

I have collected some data, and I want to quantify how heavy the tail of its underlying probability distribution is.

I believe that the tail is described reasonably well by a Weibull distribution $W(\alpha, \beta)$, so inferring the shape parameter of $W$ should give me an idea about the tail heaviness. However, I'm not sure that a Weibull distribution is a good model for the bulk of the distribution, so I would not like to just fit a distribution to all of the data.

I thought about censoring all data that is not inside the tail (below a threshold) and infer the Weibull parameters based on the censored data, and it seems to work fine. But is there a better / more common way?

Comment: Have you looked into extreme value theory ?

Comment: Look at extreme value theory, like @Pohoua mentioned. Depending on the nature of your data, have a look at the Fisher-Tippet theorem (with GEV distribution - the Weibull is a case of the GEV actually) (data is block maxima) or look at the Pickands-Balkema-de Haan theorem (with generalized Pareto distribution) (data is over some threshold).